# Slow query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query

```
SELECT 1

FROM  GEM_001_2014.LINEAS L INNER JOIN GEM_001_2014.ALBARANES A
ON(L.NUM_SERIE = A.NUM_SERIE AND L.NUM_ALBARAN = A.NUM_ALBARAN)

WHERE
      (  L.COD_ART LIKE '%1l%' )

ORDER BY A.FECHA DESC  LIMIT 500
```

and this query spend 20 seconds... if i remove the ORDER AND LIMIT spend 6 seconds and if i remove WHERE sentence spend 0.004 seconds...

explain is

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'A', 'index', 'PRIMARY', 'INDICE_3', '32', '', 83, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'L', 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '35', 'gem_001_2014.A.NUM_SERIE,gem_001_2014.A.NUM_ALBARAN', 6, 'Using where'
```

LINEAS Table have 486164 rows
and 
ALBARANES table have 5903 rows

Why this slow??

both tables have primary index, LINEAS in NUM_SERIE,NUM_ALBARAN,NUM_LINEA, and ALBARANES in NUM_SERIE,NUM_ALBARAN

Thanks!

Comment: query is slow for `where L.COD_ART LIKE '%1l%'`. Even if `COD_ART` is indexed it will fail to use it since like wild-card with `%someval%` can not use index where `%someval` or `someval%` does.

Answer (score 0):

Some performance tuning tips:

Any time you have a question about a performace problem in MySQL **please** post the [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) for it.  This is the first thing you need to performance tune a query.

That said.....

You probably need an index on `A.FECHA` if you are going to use it in an order by and doing a `LIKE '%whatever%'` is going to be tough on performance.  Maybe look at full [text indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) but performance is often a problem with open ended wild card searches.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE filters can only use the characters before the first wildcard during bitmap tree traversal.  Your first character is a wildcard rendering the index unusable.

Comment: the characters is a sample for force to find 0 results